# What is the relation between the eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jacobian

For the first part of part (b) I get the result by using a similarity transformation  $ x=Rx^{*}$ but I am not sure how to go about the relation between their eigenvectors.

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $v$ is an eigenvector of $B$, then $Rv$ is an eigenvector of $A$: if $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ is such that $Bv=\lambda v$, then$$Bv=\lambda v\iff R^{-1}ARv=\lambda v\iff A(Rv)=\lambda Rv.$$By a similar argument, if $w$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then $R^{-1}w$ is an eigenvector of $B$.

Comment: is it asking for the relation between the eigenvectors of matrix A and B or the relation within the eigenvectors of A?

Comment: @chloeloughan Oops! I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Comment: I get the relations in the opposite way to you? i.e. if v is an eigenvector of B then Rv is an eigenvector of A and if w is an eigenvector of A then R-1w is an eigenvector of B.

Comment: @chloeloughan Right once again. I've expanded my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Relation between the eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$:

if $Ax= \mu x$, then put $y=R^{-1}x$ and show that $By= \mu y$.